# HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `goodfor_what`.`name`) = 3 cause error message

Tags: mysql, sql

I got error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT goodfor_when.name) = 1 .

Here is part of the query where error happen

```
                    ....
        WHERE 
        ( `city`.`name` = "London" ) AND 
        `goodfor_what`.`name` IN ("Beers","Wine","Food") 
        GROUP BY name 

        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `goodfor_what`.`name`) = 3 AND `goodfor_when`.`name` IN ('Daytime') GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `goodfor_when`.`name`) = 1 ORDER BY `t`.`name`, `t`.`id`;
```

But works if remove line

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `goodfor_what`.`name`) = 3 AND `goodfor_when`.`name` IN ('Daytime') GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have two `HAVING` or two `GROUP BY` commands in the same query, and the `GROUP BY` must be placed before the `HAVING`. So, for instance :

```
GROUP BY name
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT `goodfor_what`.`name`) = 3 AND `goodfor_when`.`name` IN ('Daytime'))
OR COUNT(DISTINCT `goodfor_when`.`name`) = 1 
ORDER BY `t`.`name`, `t`.`id`;
```

And more, unless `t.id` is an aggregated column, you'll have to `SELECT t.id` and `GROUP BY t.id` if you want to `ORDER BY t.id`